# Implementing Graph by AdjacencyLists

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, hashtable, prims-algorithm

I want to implement (in Java) a Graph class using `AdjacencyLists`, I'd use this class on minimum spanning tree for `Prim's` Algorithm.

I read that there's many way for doing this but I can't use data structures built upon simpler primitive data types (`LinkedList`, stack and so on) so I thought that maybe a good solution would be using `HashTable` and merge them with `ArrayList` instead of `LinkedList`.

I read that the goal of merging `LinkedList` with `HashTable` is merging advantages of `LinkedList` (optimal enumeration of adjacency list of vertex) and `HashTable` (fast searching and adding edges).

I'm wondering about two things:

- Would I keep those proprieties by using ArrayList instead of LinkedList?
- Would it be better using HashTable linked to another HashTable?

  Any other suggestion? If I use `HashTable`, what would be the best way to solve collisions? I was thinking about Separate Chaining.

Comment: Are you referring to a specific language and framework?

Comment: I'm gonna do this in Java. @Codor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you desired Graph structure would be a `HashTable<Vertex,ArrayList<Pair<Vertex,Float>>>` mapping each vertex to its adjacent together with an edge weight.

You can use an ArrayList since you don't need to remove processed edges from the adjacency list.

In general I would not recommend linking the HashTable to a second one due to memory usage because the algorithm processes all adjacent edges of a vertex. Only if you wanted to remove a processed edge, it would help you to remove the edge for the other direction.

Note that while the HashMap + ArrayList approach is space efficient and sufficient for this algorithm [to run in O(V^2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm), it is not recommended for dense graphs when many edge lookups are required. Checking whether an edge from A to B exists is linear in the number of adjacent vertices of A or B. If you want to retrieve them in O(1), you would want a second HashTable to store the edges. An example is given in the [JGraphT Library](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/blob/master/jgrapht-core/src/main/java/org/jgrapht/graph/specifics/FastLookupDirectedSpecifics.java).

Note also that it's generally recommended [to use HashMap over HashTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)

Comment: Ok, so HashMap + LinkedList would be best solution to approach this problem but HashMap + ArrayList would be ok as well. I have to pay attention on removing edges but I won't have any problem for the others basic operation - right?

Comment: Unless you want to add an Edge to the ArrayList not at the end, but at a specific position, yes. And while it's nothing you need to worry about in 'real life', there is a different time complexity for adding elements: For LinkedLists, it's truly O(1); for ArrayLists, it's just _amortized_ constant time because the array [needs to be resized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).